# How to connect to a Node.js WebSocket Server from a port forwarded server?

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, xampp, portforwarding

I am trying out a chat program using HTML5 app and Node.js WebSocket on my computer, following the video https://youtu.be/hv9KdklXZqE.

The Node.js WebSocket listens to port 5555 and is at C:\xampp\htdocs\TestWebSocketServer. On the client side, we have a HTML5 website in XAMPP server also on my computer at C:\xampp\htdocs\TestWebsocket_client

We would like to send some messages from our client to the WebSocket server on my computer. My computer is in a LAN network behind our Main Server that is accessible online. (Let's assume it is named "http://exampleSite.com".)

To do this, we did a fixed IP address on my computer and did a port forwarding in the Main Server which points to my computer. We chose port forwarding port 5555.

To ensure my computer is accessible to outsiders on the Internet, we set the Firewall to allow network communication both public and private for apps such as node.exe and Evented I/O for V8 Javascript.

And to test that the computer is globally accessible, we tried access "http://exampleSite.com:5555/". The result is we can access the index.html and other files that resides in XAMPP's htdocs directory in my computer correctly.

To test WebSocket, we run our Node.js WebSocket server. Then we open our http://exampleSite.com:5555/TestWebsocket_client/ , our HTML5 site runs correctly, but then when we try to connect to the Node.js WebSocket, we got the error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://exampleSite.com:5555/' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

---

**Codes**

For the client side code, it is actually Construct 2 exported HTML5. We are using exactly 3 lines of same codes at https://youtu.be/hv9KdklXZqE?t=6m45s

For the server side code, the same code is also from the video above at https://youtu.be/hv9KdklXZqE?t=7m7s

We have verified in our localhost environment just like in the video that the client C2 side can connect to our Node.js server without any problem.

---

How to connect to the Node.js WebSocket Server in this case?